# Type of values() method

Tags: java

I can't find anywhere what is the type returned by the method values() in HashMap.
In fact, as I want to use it in a different class than the one who has the hashmap I want to iterate through, I'd like to do an accessor in the right class to this method like this :

```
    public xxxxxx values(){
return this.values();
}
```

What should I put instead of the "xxxxxx" ?

Comment: Did you see the java docs for this?

Comment: yes. it says "Collection", but when I write this, it doesn't work, it says it can't find this class.

Comment: Did you bother to `import` it?

Comment: if u r a beginner in java then you need to import the COllection interface by writing import java.util.Collection; after the package declaration

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()

Answer (score 4):

It returns **`java.util.Collection<v>`**

Where `v` is a Type of your Value in your Map

Check the [**API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29):

```
Collection<V> values()
```

Comment: The API is the first place to look, after that you can also look at the sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the `Collection<V>`

You can see it in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29)

Comment: Down voter, can you please explain the reason? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your map is parametrized as `HashMap<K,V>` then `values()` will return a collection of type `V`.

Answer (score 0):

As per API:

**values()** - Returns a collection view of the values contained in this map. It returns of type **java.util.Collection**

Answer (score 0):

it will return type is java.util.List and keyset will return Set

Comment: `values()` returns a `Collection` and not `List`